# How do I limit default user permissions (deny setup of printers)

Tags: windows-10, permissions, printer, network-printer

In an office I want to prevent a default user to setup new printers. They are supposed to use only one printer and not set up another printer. I was asked to make sure, that no one can add another printer or scanner or any similar device except for the full administrator account.

I already limited the user's account to "default user" but then I was still able to seek network printers and add them.

The user on this computer is supposed to have access to Windows network and Azure but shall not add new devices.

How do I prevent that without making the default user use a guest account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using group policy:

Open the run dialogue from the desktop by "Holding the windows key and pressing R"

Type "GPEDIT.MSC"

Navigate to "User Configuration" -> "Administrative Templates" -> "Control Panel" -> "Printers"

You should then see 2 policies in the right-hand pane "Prevent addition of printers" & "Prevent deletion of printers" if you double click on both of these you will be able to change the setting from "Not Configured" to "Enabled" this will then prevent the user from adding or deleting printers.

I believe this is only applicable to the signed in user and would require to be done to each of the users on that computer.